# How do I avoid the 'no such session' error in my afterEach hook with Nighwatch?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, end-to-end

I try to do a test suite in which I navigate in all pages of my application and I check that I do not have log errors. This code works, but I would like to avoid the log test duplication:

```
var assert = require('assert');

module.exports = {
  'open index': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.containsText('h1', 'index');

    browser.getLog(function(logs){
      assert(logs.length === 0, "Console log error(s):\n" + JSON.stringify(logs, null, 2));
    });

    browser
      .end();
  },

  'open about': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000/about')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.containsText('h1', 'about');

    browser.getLog(function(logs){
      assert(logs.length === 0, "Console log error(s):\n" + JSON.stringify(logs, null, 2));
    });

    browser
      .end();
  }
};
```

I tried to add an `afterEach` hook, but It raises 'no such session' error

```
var assert = require('assert');

module.exports = {
  'open index': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.containsText('h1', 'index')
      .end();
  },

  'open about': function(browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000/about')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.containsText('h1', 'about')
      .end();
  },

  afterEach: function(browser, done) {
    browser.getLog(function(logs){
      assert(logs.length === 0, "Console log error(s):\n" + JSON.stringify(logs, null, 2));
    });
    done();
  },
};
```

Error:

```
✖ AssertionError: Console log error(s): - expected "true" but got: "false"
{
  "message": "no such session\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.11.3-202.fc25.x86_64 x86_64)"
}
    at Object.<anonymous> (tests/e2e/specs/noErrorLogs.js:37:7)
```